# How to open Lightbox in wix.com onbeforeunload (when user wants to leave website)?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, velo

My site is hosted on wix.com. I want to display my custom lightbox when user wants to leave website.
Simple javascript would be:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   alert("Wait! Don't miss this life-transforming online event.");
}
```

but, I guess, I need it inside of onReady function (this is how they want it):

```
$w.onReady(function () {
   // open popup
   wixWindow.openLightbox("wait-with-form");
} );
```

I created my custom lightbox titled "wait-with-form". Problem is wix.com blocks direct access to `window` and `document` objects. And they only allow few of the event handlers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This will not be directly possible. You might need to embed an HTML iFrame and write the window.onbeforeunload on that and see if it works.

Comment: As January 7, 2021. Wix support says: _"Currently, it is not possible to trigger a lightbox when a visitor attempts to leave your site."_ - [Triggering a Lightbox when a Visitor Attempts to Leave Your Site](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-request-triggering-a-lightbox-when-a-visitor-attempts-to-leave-your-site)